kernel compiling "out of memory" -> kernel panic
I decided to recompile the latest kernel config-6.1.0-28-amd64 of my debian 12.
Everything went fine but once I rebooted the system it returned me a kernel panic after
a laconic "out of memory".
The initrd is actually huge but I have 36 Gb of ram and it shouldn't be a problem.
The following are the monitor's dumps:
Loading Linux 6.12.5
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: out of memory.

Press any key to continue...

and
[...]
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on "UUID=b704193c-6f59-46cd-bd15"
CPU: 4 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.12.5 #3
Hardware name: Acer Nitro AN515-55/Ignis_ADH, BIOS U2.13 03/08/2024
[...]
Kernel Offset: 0x1ea00000 from 0xffffff811000000 (relocation range: 0xffffff8118e00000-0xffffff81f0000000)

it says that it cannot find the root fs but it actually is where it is looking it for.
here's the fstab
UUID=b704193c-6f59-46cd-bd19-5b3b59a96f2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

and I compiled the ext4 drv
any suggestion?
thanks in advance

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698890/out-of-memory-on-loading-initial-ramdisk-after-kernel-upgrade-4-15-to-4-19-o
